# Awk regexp not working

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a very simple awk script that is supposed to extrapolate some log lines with a regex. I'm testing it but if I do this:

```
awk -F ' ' '$5 ~ /MyClassName/ {p=1} p {print $5}' myLogFile.log
```

I get lines from other classes even if the output should be only lines containing MyClassName.

Can anyone explain me what's wrong with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you reset p to zero?

Comment: I've just realized that I'm an idiot... It's working now... If you write an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never reset `p` back to zero.

```
awk -F ' ' '{p=0} $5 ~ /MyClassName/ {p=1} p {print $5}' myLogFile.log
```

Comment: I don't know, probably a simplification of a real case where you need to check a condition and reuse it later?

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid using `p` altogether and AFAIK setting `FS` (`-F`) to a literal space is the same as not setting it as all:

```
awk '$5 ~ /MyClassName/ {print $5}' myLogFile.log
```

And since you are only interested in column 5 you should be able to use:

```
awk '{$0=$5} /MyClassName/' myLogFile.log
```